# Can't access queryset object id in serializer when setting source for field

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using Django REST Framework I have the following serializer:

```
class TagSelectOptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    label = serializers.CharField(source='title')
    value = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('value', 'label')
        read_only_fields = ('value', 'label', )
```

When trying to use it in my view (see below) I get the following error:

`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'`

Can anyone tell me how I can access the primary key field, like I am accessing the title field in the above serializer?

```
class TagSelectOptions(APIView):
    """
    ...
    """

    def get(self, request):
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(approved=True)

        if len(tags) > 1:
            serializer = TagSelectOptionsSerializer(tags, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = TagSelectOptionsSerializer(tags)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=rest_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get method is incorrect.

When the length of the results in less than or equal to 1 you should still send many=True.

Because the behavior of the API should remain same. The JSON scheme will return a list of objects in all cases.

So change the code to:

```
def get(self, request):
    tags = Tag.objects.filter(approved=True)
    # handles all cases by default
    serializer = TagSelectOptionsSerializer(tags, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=rest_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But if you really want to return only a single object when the queryset returns only a single result then use:

```
def get(self, request):
    tags = Tag.objects.filter(approved=True)

    if len(tags) == 1:
        serializer = TagSelectOptionsSerializer(tags[0])
    else:
        # when len > 1 or len == 0
        serializer = TagSelectOptionsSerializer(tags, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=rest_status.HTTP_200_OK)
```